# Strange problem with java CardLayout in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, cardlayout

hello i have a Jframe with a CardLayout and 3 cards.
I have an ActionListener on a button on the first card.

This code is working well:

```
JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
        cl.show(cards, "wait");
    }
}
```

the problem is when i add code to do the login on the server (i'm developing an xmpp client):

```
JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
        cl.show(cards, "wait");
        xmppManager = new Xmpp("jabberserver", 5222);
        try {
            xmppManager.init();
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cl.show(cards, "userList");
    }
}
```

Basically, i need to show a "please wait" card when the user press the login button, do the login, and then show another card. But in this case, the "wait" card doesn't show, it do the login (it take around 5 seconds) and it show directly the final card "userList".

What i'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the code is executing on the Event Dispatch Thread which is preventing the GUI from repainting itself. You need the call to the server to execute in a separate Thread so you don't block the EDT.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial  on [Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information and a suggested solution.

Comment: Hi thank you! Now i closed the server call in EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {    public void run() { //server call } and it is working, do you think it's a good solution?

Comment: I don't see a need to do server manipulation on the EDT, unless I am misinterpreting your post.  You should click on the link in camickr's post above to learn about using a SwingWorker object to help you do background threads in Swing.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is necessary to trigger a repaint of the screen after you show the please wait? It might not be triggered automatically.

Comment: Hi thank you. I just added a frame.repaint(); after cl.show(cards, "wait");
but it doens change. it's stuck on the first card and, after the login, it go directly to the 3th card...

Comment: just tryed cards.repaint() too. nothing.

Comment: For CardLayout, this is not necessary. camickr's post best describes the problem and its solution.